# About AngularJS Toggle

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new AngularJS , and I have modify jquery code to directive
When I click on one of these numbers, 
TOGGLE unable action
Can anyone help me ..

[This is my code in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duketopmost/t7wwp8wr/)

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .directive("myNumber", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        template: "<div id='hktable' class='numberBorder'></div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            var i, j;
            var hktable = element.find("#hktable");
            hktable.append("<div class='row' id=rowhead></div>");
            var rowhead = element.find("#rowhead");
            rowhead.append("<div class='rowhead0' </div>");
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                rowhead.append("<div class='rowhead' id=rowhead" + i + "></div>");
            }

            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                hktable.append("<div class='row' id=Row" + i + "></div>");
                var row = element.find("#Row" + i);
                row.append("<div class='colhead' id=colhead" + i + "></div>");
                for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                    var strNumber = i.toString() + j.toString();
                    row.append("<div class='colNumber'>" +
                        "<div class='Ball' " +
                        "ng-class={'Ball':!isActive ,'Ball active':isActive} " +
                        "ng-init='isActive=false' " +
                        "ng-click='isActive=!isActive' " +
                        "id=Ball" + strNumber + ">" + strNumber + "</div></div>");
                }
            }
            //$("#Ball00").text("L");
            //$("#Ball00").attr("id", "head");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add ng-show="!isActive"

```
<div class="Ball" 
        ng-class="{'Ball':!isActive,'Ball active':isactive}" 
        ng-init="isActive=false" ng-click="isActive=!isActive" 
        id="Ball99" ng-show="!isActive">99</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I was let down by MOUSE change other colors, instead of hiding ~
In jquery code, I wrote the code, html code generated in the following way into it
  ng-class = "{'Ball':! isActive", 'ball active': isactive} "